# How to make PWA with manifest / service-worker?

Tags: json, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I have got a syntax error in my manifest.json

> Manifest : Line : 7, column: 1, Syntax error.

I'm trying to delete all datas in the file and I get the same error.

Look at my manifest.json

```
{
"name" : "VIDEOFUTUR",
"short_name" : "VF",
"description" : "Télécom",
"start_url" : "index.php",
"scope" : "/",
"display" : "fullscreen",
"orientation" : "any",
"lang" : "French",
"icons" : [
    {
        "src": "https://lafibrevideofutur.fr/img/favicon.png",
        "sizes": "256x256"
    }],
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error? In a the browser console?

Comment: Yes in the browser console. 
When I open the manifest in the console for look at the line 7, I got this error 
"Nothing to preview"

Answer (score 0):

Have you spotted that stray comma after the `icons`?

Should be:

```
{
   "name": "VIDEOFUTUR",
   "short_name": "VF",
   "description": "Télécom",
   "start_url": "index.php",
   "scope": "/",
   "display": "fullscreen",
   "orientation": "any",
   "lang": "French",
   "icons": [
      {
         "src":"https://lafibrevideofutur.fr/img/favicon.png",
         "sizes":"256x256"
      }
   ]
}
```

Next time simply validate your JSON using any [online tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=json%20validator).

Comment: Thx to your answer, but I got again the same error.I can delete the file and I have again always the same error

Comment: Where is this error coming from? It's a perfectly fine web manifest. Is it possible the file got cached somehow?

Comment: Normally it's not possible. I looked this option and I don't see something

Comment: I've just used that manifest in a simple `index.html` of mine and it's perfectly fine and the browser doesn't report any errors.